# How much film do I need (in feet/meters)?

Tags: filming

I'm shooting 3-perf 35mm @ 24 fps. How many feet of film do I need if I'm shooting one hour?

Is there a good site/app for calculating this?

Note: This is a repost of [an off-topic/closed question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/638/how-much-film-do-i-need-in-feet-meters) I asked on Photography - Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

4,051 feet of film.

For reference:

- 8mm = 80.0 frames per foot
- Super 8 = 72.0 frames per foot
- 16mm = 40.0 frames per foot
- 35mm 2-perf = 32.0 frames per foot
- 35mm 3-perf = 21.3 frames per foot
- 35mm = 16.0 frames per foot
- 65mm = 12.8 frames per foot

The math:

> 60 minutes = 3600 seconds, 3600 sec x 24 fps = 86,400 frames, 86,400/21.333 = 4,050.06328

**Tools for Calculating**

Kodak makes a free app for iOS called "KODAK Cinema Tools" which has a film calculator, among other features.

http://motion.kodak.com/US/en/motion/Tools/Mobile/index.htm

Panavision has a simple website with a film footage, frame and running time calculator:

http://www.panavision.co.nz/main/kbase/reference/calcfootage.asp

Comment: +1 Great answer.  (by the way, no need to put "Hope this helps" at the end of your answer)

Comment: Thank you Fried Of George, I work at a helpdesk for a living, and 'hope this helps' is a habit that I will have to learn to break. :>